# Save a multiline string to a text file without overwriting previous text

Tags: java, string, file, text

Ok, so I am trying to save a multi-line string to a text file, without overwriting the previous text. println perfectly prints it, but saving to to a text file only seems to save the first line.

What I have so far (writes without overwriting, but only writes first line):

```
                    try {
                        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(FileManager.usernames, true);

                        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                        bufferedWriter.write(multilineString + "\n");
                        bufferedWriter.close();
                    } 
                    catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

The answer to this is probably simple, but I am new to Java.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your problem. You are writing a single string into the file. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: You are writing a single string. According to your code,if you keep on writing a single string to a file, the new contents will keep on getting appended. I hope that is what you wanted? So what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I want to make it so it writes the whole string (there are multiple lines in the string) to a text file, but it only currently writes the first line.

Comment: EDIT: fixed the problem, it was something else stopping it from being written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try `bufferedWriter.flush();` Here is code snippet which may help you

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteIntoFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String multilineString = "This is line 1\nthis is line 2\nthis is last line";
           try {
               FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("multiline.txt", true);

               BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
               bufferedWriter.write(multilineString + "\n");
               bufferedWriter.flush();
               bufferedWriter.close();
               fileWriter.close();
           } 
           catch(IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

    }

}
```